# How can I disable ipv6 on Ubuntu Server 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I'm trying to run Dell OMSA on Ubuntu 8.04.  However, it's binding to ipv6 and not to an ipv4 address.  I can't seem to figure out how to change this behavior.

So, since I don't need ipv6 support, I'd like to just disable it and see if that clears things up.

I've tried blacklisting ipv6 in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist (blacklist ipv6), and turning it off in /etc/modprobe.d/aliases (alias net-pf-10 off).  I'm seeing both solutions recommended in forums and blogs, but neither works.

Comment: Have you tried using "alias net-pf-10 off ipv6" instead of "alias net-pf-10 off" ?

Comment: Oops.  Yeah, ipv6 is still enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't". While there are a few ways to try and hack it off they usually don't stick over kernel upgrades.

The output of `netstat -tul` might be helpful.